# How to get index with multiple values but return single result

Tags: ruby, indexing, ruby-1.8.7

I have two arrays:

```
expected = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
actual = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "d", "g", "g"]
```

I converted both to string like this:

```
expected1 = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g"
actual1 = "a,b,c,d,d,g,g"
```

I will compare each value if they are the same, like: `expected1[0] == actual1[0]`, `expected1[1] == actual[1]` and so on. If they are not the same, I like to get the index of the file from actual. In this case, it is not equal on `expected1[4]` and `actual[4]` since the values are `"e"` and `"d"`.

I did `actual1.index(actual[4])`, but since the value is `"d"`, the first result will be returned. I expect a return value of  `"8"`, but since there is a first `"d"`, it would return a value of `"6"`.

Is there an alternative way to do this?

Comment: Please explain what you've tried (include code), and what you expect to see as output.

Comment: So far you're explaining exactly how it should work... what is the problem? (also "8" and "6"  are not the indexes of "d" in your given example, you may have meant "4" and "3" ? )

Comment: @TarynEast to get the "8", the comma is included. Since the value is in string.

Comment: @MarkThomas the above code was the best that i tried. Right now, im really stuck with this problem. If the value is unique though, I dont really have a problem with the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after further researching,  the code below works :

```
diff = []

actual[row_num].join(",").scan(actual[row_num][col_num]) do |c|

  diff << [c, Regexp.last_match.offset(0).first]   

end
```

I applied this on the logic of my code. I first converted the Array to String using JOIN including Commas. And scan each ROW & COLUMN.

I then call each result as **diff.last[1]**, to get the exact INDEX.

Hopefully this helps someone the same as my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain why you converted the arrays to strings at this point. If you did this comparison while they are still in array form, you could do something like this, if you want to return the *first* mismatched value:

```
actual.each_with_index |char, idx|
  if char != expected1[idx]
    return idx
  end
end
```

If you want to return a *list* of mismatched values, you could do something like this:

```
wrong_value_indices = []

actual.each_with_index |char, idx|
  if char != expected1[idx]
    wrong_value_indices << idx
  end
end

return wrong_values_indices
```

'return' is of course optional. This may not be perfect Ruby style, but it should help to illustrate a solution pattern. [Here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) is a link to the Enumerable#each_with_index documentation. Hope this helps!

EDIT: In string form, you could have an exterior index. Again, I know this is very toy-ish code, but if you just want ANY solution for what you're asking...

```
idx = 0
actual1.each_char |char|
  if char != expected1[idx]
    return idx
  end
  idx += 1
end
```

or

```
wrong_value_indices = []

idx = 0
actual.each_char |char|
  if char != expected1[idx]
    wrong_value_indices << idx
  end
  idx += 1
end

return wrong_values_indices
```

Comment: Hi Andrelton, thanks for this. This works fine on array. I converted it to String to show which column on the CSV file is affected or mismatch (for Actual File). I included also the comma as part of the string, since when indexing, comma is part of counting. I will then check on an Editor or GEdit manually, to view the column and row number of the affected files. Unfortunately, this did not solve the initial problem.